# Is there a better way to write this equation

Tags: equations

I'm pretty sure that the following equation could be better presented, I just don't get how am I suppose to do:

```
    In matrix form : 
\begin{equation}
Y = X\vec{\omega} \quad mit\quad Y\in${\rm I\!R}$^{n\times1}, X\in${\rm I\!R}$\^{n\times d} und \omega\in${\rm I\!R}$\^{d\times1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \iff
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \hat{y_1} \\
     \vdots \\
     \hat{y_n} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      x_{11} & \cdots &x_{1d}\\
      \vdots & \vdots &\vdots\\
      x_{n1} &\cdots &x_{nd}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    \omega_d
  \end{bmatrix}
  \quad mit \quad x_{11}\cdots x_{n1} =1
\end{equation}
```

here is what I get:[image]

Is there any hint how may  improve the look of this equation !

Greatfull for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part I propose:

```
Y = X\vec{\omega} \quad \text{mit}\quad Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}, X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d} \,\, \text{und}\,\,  \omega\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times1}
```

[image]

or an improved version

```
Y = X\vec{\omega} \quad \text{mit}\quad (Y,X,\omega)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}\times\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}\times\mathbb{R}^{d\times1}
```

[image]

For the second part:

```
 \iff
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \hat{y_1} \\
     \vdots \\
     \hat{y_n} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      x_{11} & \cdots &x_{1d}\\
      \vdots & \vdots &\vdots\\
      x_{n1} &\cdots &x_{nd}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    \omega_d
  \end{bmatrix}
  \quad \text{mit}\,\, \forall i\in\llbracket 1,n\rrbracket,\, x_{i1} =1
```

[image]

The full equation could be obtained:

```
Y = X\vec{\omega} \quad \text{mit}\quad (Y,X,\omega)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}\times\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}\times\mathbb{R}^{d\times1}
\iff
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \hat{y_1} \\
     \vdots \\
     \hat{y_n} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      x_{11} & \cdots &x_{1d}\\
      \vdots & \vdots &\vdots\\
      x_{n1} &\cdots &x_{nd}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    \omega_d
  \end{bmatrix}
  \quad \text{mit}\,\, \forall i\in\llbracket 1,n\rrbracket,\, x_{i1} =1
```

[image]

**NB:**

- for obtaining the `\rrbracket` and `\llbracket` you need to add `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` before `\begin{document}`.
- In my equation I also like to add bold font for matrices and vectors but it depends on your way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `align` environment or the `alignat` environment :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

  In matrix form :
\begin{align}
Y & = X\vec{\omega} \quad \text{mit}\: Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}, \:X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d} \text{ und } \omega\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times1}\\
  \iff
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \hat{y_1} \\
     \vdots \\
     \hat{y_n} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  & = \begin{bmatrix}
      x_{11} & \cdots &x_{1d}\\
      \vdots & \vdots &\vdots\\
      x_{n1} &\cdots &x_{nd}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    \omega_d
  \end{bmatrix}
  \quad \text{mit} \: x_{11}\cdots x_{n1} =1.
\end{align}
\bigskip

or this way:
\begin{alignat}{2}
& & Y & = X\vec{\omega} \quad \text{mit}\: Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}, \:X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d} \text{ und } \omega\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times1}\\
\ArrowBetweenLines
   & &
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \hat{y_1} \\
     \vdots \\
     \hat{y_n} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  & = \begin{bmatrix}
      x_{11} & \cdots &x_{1d}\\
      \vdots & \vdots &\vdots\\
      x_{n1} &\cdots &x_{nd}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    \omega_d
  \end{bmatrix}
  \quad \text{mit} \: x_{11}\cdots x_{n1} =1.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What about this? I realised that Guuk was ahead.

```
\begin{equation}
Y = X\vec{\omega} \quad \text{mit}\quad (Y,X,\omega)\in R^{n\times 1}\times R^{n\times d}\times R^{d\times 1}\;
\iff\;
\begin{bmatrix}
 \hat{y_1} \\
 \vdots \\
 \hat{y_n} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & x_{12} & \cdots &x_{1d}\\
  \vdots & \vdots &\vdots\\
  1 & x_{n2} &\cdots &x_{nd}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_1 \\
\vdots \\
\omega_d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}% probably better

\newcommand{\R}{\mathrm{I}\!\mathrm{R}}% very old fashioned


\begin{document}

In Matrixform:
\begin{align}
& \text{$Y = X\vec{\omega}$ mit $Y\in\R^{n\times1}$,
        $X\in\R^{n\times d}$ und $\omega\in\R^{d\times1}$}
\\
&\iff
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \hat{y_1} \\
     \vdots \\
     \hat{y_n} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      x_{11} & \cdots &x_{1d}\\
      \vdots & \vdots &\vdots\\
      x_{n1} &\cdots &x_{nd}
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    \omega_d
  \end{bmatrix}
  \text{ mit } x_{11}\cdots x_{n1} =1
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]